# Second router as repeater

Tags: home-networking

I've connected my second Fritzbox Router to the Main Fritzbox Router to extend my WIFI signal. But now I' m having trouble with the connected devices like Printer, TV, Smartphones and so on, because they are no longer on the same network. They all are connected through the WIFI to the Main Router and only some time to the Second Router.

[image]

**Main Router**

DSL goes to the internet connection
LAN 1 goes to the Second Router
[image]

**Second Router**

LAN 1 comes from Main Router
Yellow Cable comes from My PC
[image]

So, my question is, how to configure my Network so that the devices will be on the same network no matter are they connected to the Main Router or Second Router?

Here is My Second Router Settings:

[image]

And I assume this are the settings I need to configure, right?

[image]

Comment: The second router needs to be set to bridge mode.

Comment: You can configure your second Fritzbox to run as a repeater. The first one can then take control over the entire network and even manage the second box like other compatible IoT devices.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you plug in the network cable from the first router into the WAN port.

This essentially means that you are creating a network inside a network.

Either setup the second router to be in bridge mode, or bypass the entire router by changing the network cable from WAN to a LAN port.

Comment: Yeah this was suggested by the router during installation, and I've added some photos.

Comment: @khashashin - disable the DHCP server on the second box and make sure all IPS are in the same network, is change 192.168.188.1 to something in 192.168.178 or change the netmask on all devices to something that includes both ranges, eg 255.255.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned Fritzbox in my question, but I know that there is a chance that no one in the superuser community is using this device and cannot give me a specific answer about my router configuration. So I figured it out myself and added a new custom "Service Provider". To do this, you need to select " Other Internet Service Provider" and name your new configuration. In my case I created a new service provider and named it "WiFi Repeater" and now I have the following configuration of the router:

[image]

After that, the current connection of the second Router will be lost, as it will get a new IP address. You can access the main Router via http://fritz.box and below the network information you will see the Second Router connected and its new IP address.